# How do i get the subject at average of my student with registeration 17015?

Tags: mysql

Below is the table data that i am using as my reference point:

```
mysql> select subject_title,grand_total from transcript where regno='17015' and form='JSS 1';
```

Output:

```
 BASIC SCIENCES              :  237,
 CHRISTIAN RELIGION STUDY    :  198,
 CIVIC EDUCATION             :  187,
 COMPUTER STUDIES            :  206,
 ECONOMICS                   :  196,
 FRENCH                      :  192,
 MATHEMATICS                 :  221,
 PHYSICAL AND HEALTH EDUCATION: 245,
 SOCIAL STUDIES              :  238,
 ENGLISH                     :  195.
```

Question is: How do i get my student subject at AVERAGE using MySQL database?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT subject_title, AVG(grand_total) AS average
FROM transcript
WHERE regno = '17015' AND form = 'JSS 1';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT subject_title, grand_total, AVG(grand_total) As average_total
    -> FROM transcript 
    -> WHERE regno='17015' and form='JSS 1';
```

or

```
mysql> SELECT subject_title,AVG(grand_total) As average_total
    -> FROM transcript 
    -> WHERE regno='17015' and form='JSS 1';
```

To learn about [Average Function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-avg-function.htm)

Comment: @ Abdulla: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is not yet solved, i tried the above code solution provided  by u and it gives me an output of '211.5' of which none of my reference subjects above is having 211.5 as a grand_total, So i need to know the subject at AVERAGE.

Comment: your total is 2115. so if we get average it shows 211.5.

Comment: @AguJustice what you expecting as answer??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question.  Do you need: 
(237+198+187+206+196+192+221+245+238+195)/10 (=211.5) 
which is the average of all the subjects?

Comment: for example  you know that the subject at maximum is SOCIAL STUDIES : 238. AND  subject at Minimum is CIVIC EDUCATION : 187. So my problem is, how to get the subject at AVERAGE?